# Best Practice to Highlight the Left menu using PHP

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5

## I have

a left menu , and I'm seeking the best practice to highlight the left menu using PHP.

---

## Route

```
http://localhost:8888/000D6766F2F6/network/create
http://localhost:8888/000D6766F2F6/network
```

---

## I've tried

create a function, base on my route, I grab the URL segment, and check for it's existing.

```
public static function customerTab($tab){

    $url = Request::url();
    if (strpos($url, $tab) !== FALSE){
        return 'active';
    }else{
        return '';
    }

}
```

---

## I've called it

**Network**

```
<li class="{{ Helper::customerTab('network')}}"><a href="/{!! $cpe_mac !!}/network"><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i><span>Network</span></a></li>
```

**My Network**

```
<li class="{{ Helper::customerTab('network')}}"><a href="/{!! $cpe_mac !!}/network/create"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> My Network</a></li>
```

---

Since both of the routes containing the word `network`, I don't think my approach is working. I'm opening to any advice at this moment.

Comment: Consider https://github.com/lavary/laravel-menu perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Request::is()` to determine if the current URL path matches a simple glob. It defers to `str_is()` for matching (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-str-is), so you can do very simple wildcard matching, e.g. `Request::is('*/network')` or `Request::is('*/network/*')`.

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('*/network') ? 'active' : null }}">... Network ...</li>
<li class="{{ Request::is('*/network/*') ? 'active' : null }}">... My Network ...</li>
```

Hope that helps!